# docker push with local notary server returns error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-registry, jfrog-container-registry, notary

I have been working at setting up a docker notary on a Centos 8 machine. I followed the [README.md](https://github.com/theupdateframework/notary/blob/master/README.md) for the notary project which tells me to use the testing certificate the project
comes with by moving it to the `.notary` folder in my home directory. My hope here is that when my docker client is setup for it and when I properly tag the image a docker push to my private docker repo (jFrog Artifactory) would result in a published image that is signed by the notary.

My private repo is running on its own machine and not on the machine where the notary server is running.

But every time I go for the push I get this error:

```
Signing and pushing trust metadata
Error: error contacting notary server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

One of the ways I tried to fix this is by copying over the test certificates from `fixtures/root-ca.crt` to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` after which I ran `update-ca-trust`.

```
$ sudo cp fixtures/root-ca.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
$ update-ca-trust
```

But doing this also didn't help. Why is the notary server throwing this error? Help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With docker content trust, you can add the CA to the user's home directory in a subdirectory under `~/.docker/tls`:

```
mkdir -p ~/.docker/tls/${content_trust_hostname}
cp ca.pem ~/.docker/tls/${content_trust_hostname}/ca.crt
export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1
docker push ${content_trust_hostname}/${your_repo}:${tag}
```

Note that the certificate likely needs to end with "crt" and if you don't override the content trust server, the hostname will match the registry name.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t had issues working on Azure container registry. 
Working on Jfrog registry, I had same error

Your work around helped me 
“
$ sudo cp fixtures/root-ca.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
$ update-ca-trust
“
If it helps I can post my steps
Thanks @RijoSimon

Comment: Thanks Pradeep. Yes, will you please post your steps. I would like to see if I missed something.

Comment: Seems artifactory doesn’t like self signed certs

Answer (score 0):

notary server: x509: certificate is valid for 127.0.0.1, not xx.xx.xx.xx(notaryIP)

This error is because the certificate that delivered with notary server is only valid for notary-server, notaryserver, localhost. To make it work with your remote domain, you have to get a CA that work for your ip/domain.

Answer (score -1):

Rijo my solution is not complete because This doesn’t work on remote server, facing an error

```
Error: error contacting notary server: x509: certificate is valid for 127.0.0.1, not xx.xx.xx.xx(notaryIP)
```

Here is my solution where was able to sign image locally on the notary server and push it

```
Docker login artifactoryurl 
username:
password: 
Login successful 
docker trust key generate keyname 
export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=0
docker build -f Dockerfile -t artrifactoryurl/reponame:tag .           
export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST_SERVER=http://127.0.0.1:4443   
export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1  
docker trust signer add —key keyname.pub name artifactoryurl/repo
docker trust sign artifactoryurl/reponame:tag
docker inspect artifactoryurl/reponame:tag
```

Hope it helps